# Fingerprint overlay in samsung interupt

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, fingerprint, android-fingerprint-api, samsung-mobile-sdk

for some reason if i want to listen to the Fingerprint sensor, the overlay of the Samsung fingerprint(in front fo the device) is display on the screen and prevent from me to reach the screen below the fingerprint , when i remove the listening of the Fingerprint the overlay is disappear, and no fingerprint listening is turn on.

any idea how to keep the fingerprint listening and not to display the overlay of Samsung

Comment: I guess you don't have any workaround because Samsung overridden the fingerprint sensor sequence

Comment: Any idea for workaround?